# CSS clamp() formula for font-size

Tags: css

I'm trying to understand how this tool figures out the 2nd parameter for the clamp() function: https://fluid-typography.netlify.app/. Is anyone able to explain that part?

I understand the 1st and 3rd parameters as they are pretty self-explanatory. It's the 2nd parameter that's confusing.

Minimum size `1.5rem` at a viewport width of `700px`.

Maximum size `3rem` at a viewport width of `1000px`.

```
font-size: clamp(1.5rem, 8vw - 2rem, 3rem);
```

Comment: Have you looked at [the source on Github](https://github.com/jakobsen/fluid-typography/blob/main/src/components/App.js#L24)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula is `font-size = Xvw - Yrem`. At `700px` of viewport (`100vw = 700px` so `1vw = 7px`) we want `1.5rem` (`1.5rem = 24px`) and at `1000px` (`100vw = 1000px` so `1vw = 10px`) we want `3rem` (`3rem = 48px`) so:

```
24px = X*7px  - Y*16px
48px = X*10px - Y*16px
```

Solve the equation and you will get `X = 8` and `Y = 2`

You have a linear function to define the `font-size` between `700px` and `1000px`. Outside of this range we want the font-size to be fixed that's why we use `clamp()` to have a min and max value

Answer (score 0):

`font-size: clamp(1.5rem, 8vw - 2rem, 3rem);`

As you say, the first and third parameters are fairly simple, as they both just use the `rem` unit. But the middle parameter is the result of a calculation, finding the difference between two values with different units.

`8vw` means 8% of the viewport width. `2rem` means twice the font size of the root element. So, `8vw - 2rem` means 8% of the viewport minus twice the font size of the root element. Because values in `rem` will stay the same (barring any `@media` directives in CSS changing the font size of the root element), but `vw` units scale with the size of the viewport, this means the result of that middle parameter will scale with the size of the viewport.

It's the `8vw` part that's important, since that's the part that scales with viewport width. The `- 2rem` part of that middle parameter is really just an offset to get things looking as desired at any particular viewport.

When used with `clamp()`, the resulting value will never be smaller than `1.5rem`, and it will never be larger than `3rem`, but aside from those restrictions it will be `8vw - 2rem` whenever it can.

Comment: RE: "8vw means 8% of the viewport width. 2rem means twice the font size of the root element. So, 8vw - 2rem means 8% of the viewport minus twice the font size of the root element." - I get what 8vw and 2rem means. I don't get how those values are determined based on the min and max viewport widths. Thoughts?

Comment: The value of `2rem` isn't based on the viewport width. The value of `8vw` is based on the viewport width - being 8% of it. The combination is just a simple calculation. What `clamp()` does is calculate the result of that and compare it with the first (minimum) argument and the third (maximum argument). So if `8vw - 2rem` is smaller than `1.5rem` then the `clamp()` expression resolves to `1.5rem`. The same is done for the maximum, `3rem` in this case. If `8vw - 2rem` falls between those values, then that's what `clamp()` will resolve to.

Comment: The tool accepts an input for min and max viewport widths. The values in the 2nd parameter of the clamp() function changes based on those inputs. That's what I'm curious about.

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie It's in the source code which was linked in ray's comment to your question.